# Build Spark JavaRDD List from DropResult objects

Tags: java, apache-spark

(What's possible in Scala should be possible in Java, right? But I would take Scala suggestions as well)

I am not trying to iterate over an RDD, instead I need to build one with n elements from a random/simulator class of a type called DropResult. DropResult can't be cast into anything else.

I thought the Spark "find PI" example had me on the right track but no luck. Here's what I am trying:

On a one-time basis a DropResult is made like this:
make a single DropResult from pld (PipeLinkageData)

```
DropResult dropResultSeed = pld.doDrop();
```

I am trying something like this:

```
JavaRDD<DropResult> simCountRDD = spark.parallelize(makeRangeList(1, getSimCount())).foreach(pld.doDrop());
```

I just need to run pld.doDrop() about 10^6 times on the cluster and put the results in a Spark RDD for the next operation, also on the cluster. I can't figure out what kind of function to use on "parallelize" to make this work.

makeRangeList:

```
private List<Integer> makeRangeList(int lower, int upper) {
    List<Integer> range = IntStream.range(lower, upper).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return range;    
}
```

(FWIW I was trying to use the Pi example from http://spark.apache.org/examples.html as a model of how to do a for loop to create a JavaRDD)

```
int count = spark.parallelize(makeRange(1, NUM_SAMPLES)).filter(new Function<Integer, Boolean>() {
  public Boolean call(Integer i) {
    double x = Math.random();
    double y = Math.random();
    return x*x + y*y < 1;
  }
}).count();
System.out.println("Pi is roughly " + 4 * count / NUM_SAMPLES);
```

Comment: And the point is we are trying to parallelize the process of populating the RDD in the first place, we can't run this many calculations on one machine as they take about six seconds each. Thanks for any ideas, Spark MUST be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, seems like you should be able to do this pretty easily.  Sounds like you just need to parallelize an RDD of 10^6 integers simply so that you can create 10^6 DropResult objects into an RDD.

If this is the case, I don't think you need to explicitly create a list as above.  It seems like you should just be able to use makeRange() the way the Spark Pi example does like this :

```
JavaRDD<DropResult> simCountRDD = spark.parallelize(makeRange(1,getSimCount())).map(new Function<Integer, DropResult>() 
{
  public DropResult call(Integer i) { 
     return pld.doDrop(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: I see what you are getting at, I am working on testing it now, one thing I couldn't figure out is whether makeRange is coming from a library? makeRange needs to return an array, I guess, looking at the Accumulator example http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html  ... thanks I will let you know soon

Comment: I think given the Function with DropResult it makes parallelize want a List because I am getting the error "The method parallelize(List<T>) in the type JavaSparkContext is not applicable for the arguments (int[])" ... also Function gives "The type new Function<Integer,DropResult>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Function<Integer,DropResult>.apply(Integer)" ... did clean/save in Eclipse. Since this jus tneeds to be read back to the master, I wonder if an Accumulator would work better?

Comment: Yea, I can't tell where makeRange() was supposed to come from either.  In that case, I would try this and use your original method makeRangeList() method since I don't see how an Accumulator will help :  JavaRDD<DropResult> simCountRDD = spark.parallelize(makeRangeList(1,getSimCount())).map(new Function<Integer, DropResult>() 
{
  public DropResult call(Integer i) { 
     return pld.doDrop(); 
  }
});

Comment: I am new to Spark, if I understand accumulators correctly, since they are "write-only" ie not readable by the the worker, I see them as more resource efficient, and here only the master needs to read the result.

Comment: In this case, I tried the last suggestion, I get The method map(Function<Integer,R>) in the type AbstractJavaRDDLike<Integer,JavaRDD<Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (new Function<Integer,DropResult>(){}) on map and an error on the Function arguments "The type new Function<Integer,DropResult>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Function<Integer,DropResult>.apply(Integer)" ... really appreciate the help, not sure why it's not working on my end

Comment: Still looking for more answers but I marked burgersmoke's because  it led me to the conclusion I need to break this problem down and parallelize a component part, not the whole DropResult class.