# Spark RDD, how to generate JavaRDD of length N?

Tags: java, lambda, parallel-processing, apache-spark

(part of problem is [docs that say "undocumented" on parallelize](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#parallelize%28scala.collection.Seq,%20int,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag%29) leave me reading books for examples that don't always pertain )

I am trying to create an RDD length N = 10^6 by executing N operations of a Java class we have, I can have that class implement Serializable or any Function if necessary. I don't have a fixed length dataset up front, I am trying to create one. Trying to figure out whether to create a dummy array of length N to parallelize, or pass it a function that runs N times.

Not sure which approach is valid/better, I see in Spark if I am starting out with a well defined data set like words in a doc, the length/count of those words is already defined and I just parallelize some map or filter to do some operation on that data.

In my case I think it's different, trying to parallelize the creation an RDD that will contain 10^6 elements...

DESCRIPTION:

In Java 8 using Spark 1.5.1, we have a Java method doDrop() that takes a PipeLinkageData and returns a DropResult.

I am thinking I could use map() or flatMap() to call a one to many function, I was trying to do something like this [in another question that never quite worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882283/build-spark-javardd-list-from-dropresult-objects):

```
JavaRDD<DropResult> simCountRDD = spark.parallelize(makeRange(1,getSimCount())).map(new Function<Integer, DropResult>()
    {
      public DropResult call(Integer i) { 
         return pld.doDrop(); 
      }
    });
```

Thinking something like this is more the correct approach?

```
    // pld is of type PipeLinkageData, it's already initialized

    // parallelize wants a collection passed into first param
    List<PipeLinkageData> pldListofOne = new ArrayList();

    // make an ArrayList of one
    pldListofOne.add(pld);

    int howMany = 1000000;

    JavaRDD<DropResult> nSizedRDD = spark.parallelize(pldListofOne).flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<PipeLinkageData, DropResult>() 
        { 
            public Iterable<DropResult> call(PipeLinkageData pld) {

                List<DropResult> returnList = new ArrayList();

                // is Spark good at spreading a for loop like this?
                for ( int i = 0; i < howMany ; i++ ){
                    returnList.add(pld.doDrop());  
                }

                // EDIT changed from returnRDD to returnList
                return returnList;
            }

            });
```

One other concern: A JavaRDD is corrrect here? I can see needing to call FlatMapFunction but I don't need a FlatMappedRDD? And since I am never trying to flatten a group of arrays or lists to a single array or list, do I really ever need to flatten anything?

Comment: Could explain what exactly is the logic here? I doesn't look like `pld.doDrop()` depends on anything... Are there any side effects involved? Your second attempt will return an empty RDD because there is nothing to `flatMap`. The first one looks a little bit better and 10^6 is small enough to distributed. It can be handled on a cluster though. On a side note naming lists `*RDD` is kind of confusing :)

Comment: Thanks great points! pld is a series of 20,000 to 80,000 genetic markers, each call to doDrop simulates another genotype for statistical comparison. (I think genotype is the right word, I am not the geneticist, just a lowly work-study student here)

Comment: And I thought the second example, given a single-element ArrayList, would flatmap to simply enabling the function call to operate N times, giving us an n-length RDD back? So the first approach is the right way?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882283/build-spark-javardd-list-from-dropresult-objects) Per this question about the first approach, I could never get that to work, hence the question here about the second approach :)

Comment: I missed that `pldListofOne.add(pld)`, but it is still not the way to go since it is completely sequential and puts all data on a single partition. Could you be more precise when you say you couldn't make the first version to work? A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) could be useful...

Comment: Your answer that because it's completely sequential, it will all go on one partition is gold. Thanks! Didn't realize that.  Thanks for working with me here I will do the MVCE and edit the question, probably by tomorrow morning.

Comment: @zero323 I did put together a MVCE but it seems like you have answered my question, I would appreciate anyone's help forming this into a better question, but the basic question of which approach to parallelization is valid has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first approach should work as long as `DropResult` and can be serialized `PipeLinkageData` and there are no issues with its internal logic (like depending on a shared state).
2. The second approach in a current form doesn't make sense. A single record will be processed on a single partition. It means a whole process will be completely sequential and can crash if data doesn't fit in a single worker memory. Increasing number of elements should solve the problem but it doesn't improve on the first approach
3. Finally you can initialize an empty RDD and then use `mapPartititions` replacing `FlatMapFunction` with almost identical [`MapPartitionsFunction`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/MapPartitionsFunction.java) and generate required number of objects per partition.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, you made a big difference on this project!